# Local GPO getting over written. Setting not defined in Domain GPO

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, gpo

Can a GPO expert help me out here.

I am trying to modify some of the audit policy settings on a sandbox server for testing.  When I set the policy locally, log out of the server, then log back in, it gets set back to the default value of "no auditing".

If I run a RSOP on the server, the audit policy settings I am changing are all set to "not defined".  I thought that I could change any policy I wanted on a Windows server via local GPO as long as the settings I am modifying are not defined in a GPO being pushed down from the domain.  Is that not correct?

Since there is no domain policy setting the audit settings in question, why won't the local GPO stick?

Server is running Windows 2012 R2.

Answer (score 0):

The local gpo would stick.
I assume there are colliding "classic" audit policies and advanced policies.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd408940(v=ws.10).aspx